# How to make the first option of <select> not move up down with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

I have a select list and I want to make the first option (Value) non-selectable and not able to move up and down when clicking buttons like this:

The value should always be on top

When Author is selected and pressing the up button no changes should be made. The value option must still be on top.

[image]

[image]

```
<select name="Select" title="Dropdown List" size="26" multiple="true" style="width:300" class="defaultDropdownListStyle">
  <option title="Value" value="Value" selected="true" disabled=""> Value </option>
  <option title="Author" value="Author"> Author </option>
  <option title="Title" value="Title"> Title </option>
</select>
```

How can I implement this using jquery? thank you

Edit:
Button functions

```
function btnUp()
    {
       var index = columns.elements[listbox].selectedIndex;
       var optsSelected = columns.elements[listbox].options;
       var hidden = columns.elements[hidden];
       if (index > 0)
       {
          itemsMove(index, index - 1, optsSelected);
          updateHid(hidden, optsSelected);
       }
}

   function btnDown()
        {
           var index = columns.elements[glistbox].selectedIndex;
           var selectedOptions = columns.elements[listbox].options;
           var selectedHidden = columns.elements[hidden];
           if (index >= 0 && index < optsSelected.length - 1)
           {
              itemsMove(index, index + 1, optsSelected);
              updateHid(hidden, optsSelected);
           }
    }


function itemsMove(fromIndex, toIndex, options)
{
   if (fromIndex != toIndex)
   {
         var option = options[fromIndex];
         options.remove(fromIndex);
         options.add(option, toIndex);
      }
      else
      {
         var nLength = options.length;
         var arrOptions = new Array(nLength);
         for (var i=0; i < nLength; i++)
         {
            arrOptions[i] = options[0];
            options[0] = null;
         }
         var option = arrOptions[fromIndex];
         if (toIndex < fromIndex)
         {
            for (var i = fromIndex; i > toIndex; i--)
            {
               arrOptions[i] = arrOptions[i-1];
            }
         }
         else
         {
            for (var i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++)
            {
               arrOptions[i] = arrOptions[i+1];
            }
         }
         arrOptions[toIndex] = option;
         for (var i=0; i < nLength; i++)
         {
            options[i] = arrOptions[i];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code which runs when the up and down buttons are clicked in order to debug the issue.

Comment: This depends *entirely* on how those buttons are implemented; they're not part of a standard `select`.  It could be a simple case of where the check for index==0 (top entry) change to index==1 (second entry).

Comment: in `btnUp`: `if (index > 0)` -> `if (index > 1)` and the same `btnDown` -> `if (index >= 1`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code that you're using, it's really hard to tell what you'll need to do.

In order to rewrite this section though, you'll need to grab the options in the select field, and rewrite them somehow.

So, one thing that you could try is to split the options and exclude the first index so that you're only ever touching the non-null options. Then replacing their order.

Here is a very ruff version of what I'm saying.  Let me know if this is not what you're looking for, and if you could include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be great!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let nullOption;
  let options = [];
  $('#forecastSelect option').each(function( index ) {
    if (index > 0) {
      options.push(this)
      this.remove();
    } else {
      nullOption = this
    }
  });
  
  options = options.reverse();
  
  options.forEach((option) => {
    $('#forecastSelect').append(option);
  });
  
  console.log(nullOption);
  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="forecastSelect" name="forecastSelect" title="Dropdown List" size="26" multiple="true" style="width:300" class="defaultDropdownListStyle">
  <option title="Value" value="Value" selected="true" disabled=""> Value </option>
  <option title="Author" value="Author"> Author </option>
  <option title="Title" value="Title"> Title </option>
</select>
```